# SDHC for the Wii

Tags: gaming, data-storage, performance, sd-card, video-game-console

I am looking for an SDHC for my Wii.

[Nintendo's site suggests that any SDHC up to 32 GB should (but is not guaranteed to) work](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2516/~/what-sd-cards-are-compatible%3F), while other sources imply that the file format matters if you want to use the SD card out of the box without modifying it, which is what I want to do.

Do all SDHC cards of size 32 GB or less use a FAT/FAT32 file format? I was looking at [this one](https://www.walmart.com/ip/32GB-SDSDXPK-032G-ANCIN-EXTREME-PRO-SD-300-26/157797791), as it appears to be the fastest 32 GB card available (that I could find, at least). Would this card work out of the box?

Comment: There's no need to use shortened links; they're often used by spammers to hide their links. It's best to link directly to the page.

Answer (score 1):

That card will work, but it's a UHS-II card and the Wii does not support UHS-II, so it can't use the high speeds offered by this card. In fact, the Wii is old enough that even UHS-I cards can't run at their full speed. You'd be overpaying for technology that the console can't use.

I'd probably suggest something like [this SanDisk Ultra card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0143RT8OY). They're generally reliable and are decent performers even in devices that don't have UHS support.

[Wikipedia has more information on SD card speeds.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Speeds)